# Internal site search is matching exact word only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making an eCommerce website I am using PHP and Mysql and I have some products name in table named product. How can I make a search system by which if I type "**Wallnuts**", it should return all results having word "wallnut, walnut, walnuts" and word with same pronunciation like "**valnuts**" and sorted as best matching result first. For this I am trying this by this query :

```sql
select product_name,photo,in_stock,sell_price
from $tbl_product
where product_name like '%".$q."%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '".$q."%' THEN 1
               WHEN product_name LIKE '%".$q."%' THEN 2 ELSE 3
          END) limit 0,10
```

Where $q is search string. By this query I am getting result but with only exact word match.
I need result like on [Bigbasket.com](https://www.bigbasket.com/?nc=logo) for word **wallnuts, wallnut, walnts, valnuts**.

Comment: Sounds like you need something like elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/

Comment: You can also look into the php function similar_text(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: You can use similar_text() but you must calculate lots of things and score for each record. you can use Apache Solr or Elasticsearch for this purpose.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php there is a library for matching words which sound similar. Also something similar is available in mysql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can try is `SOUNDEX()` function in MYSQL.

```
select * from mytext 
where soundex(val) LIKE CONCAT('%',SOUNDEX('wallnut'),'%')
```

This gives me **wallnuts, wallnut, walnts**.[**Check Demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4e703cfc57c1225da404befd89219366)